# Issue when changing row value based of columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which look like this:

```
status    nb_success     id 
    ok             0      A
    ok             0      A 
    ok             0      A
    nok            0      B
```

I would like to count the number of `ok` status per `id` by incrementing the `nb_success` each time the `status` is `ok`. 
So, the result I would like to get is the following dataframe:

```
status    nb_success     id 
    ok             0      A
    ok             1      A 
    ok             2      A
    nok            0      B
```

To me, the way to go would be to use [df.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), which I have done like:

```
def update_count(nb_success, status):
        if status is 'ok': 
            return nb_success + 1

dataframe['nb_success'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: update_count(row['nb_success'], row['status']), axis=1)
```

But when I try to `print` all the row where `nb_success != 0`, I got an empty Dataframe. 
`print(dataframe.loc[dataframe['nb_success'] != 0])`

What do I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of boolean mask - `True` values are converted to `1`, get Series `1,2,3...`, so need subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
mask = df['status'] == 'ok'
df.loc[mask, 'nb_success'] = mask.cumsum() - 1
print (df)
  status  nb_success id
0     ok           0  A
1     ok           1  A
2     ok           2  A
3    nok           0  B
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = df['status'] == 'ok'
df['nb_success']= df['nb_success'].mask(mask, mask.cumsum() - 1)
print (df)
  status  nb_success id
0     ok           0  A
1     ok           1  A
2     ok           2  A
3    nok           0  B
```

Solutions with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) - a bit overcomplicated:

I think you need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df ['nb_success']= df['nb_success'].mask(df['status'] == 'ok',
                                         df.groupby('status')['nb_success'].cumcount())
print (df)
  status  nb_success id
0     ok           0  A
1     ok           1  A
2     ok           2  A
3    nok           0  B
```

Similar solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['status'] == 'ok'
df.loc[mask, 'nb_success']= df[mask].groupby('status')['nb_success'].cumcount()
print (df)
  status  nb_success id
0     ok           0  A
1     ok           1  A
2     ok           2  A
3    nok           0  B
```

Comment: That works perfectly !!
Would you explain the `mask.cumsum() - 1` ? I don't get this part.

Comment: It count boolean mask - True values are converted to `1`, so count `1,2,3..` - need subtract `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
success_count = 0
def update_count(nb_success, status):
        global success_count
        if status is 'ok': 
            success_count += 1
        return success_count 

dataframe['nb_success'] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: update_count(row['nb_success'], row['status']), axis=1)
```

test this

Comment: That won't work since `success_count` is outside the scope of the function. Plus, I only want to increment the value of the `nb_success` based on the `status`.